# How can i slice an attribute within an attribute within json data?

Tags: json, apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

How can i slice an attribute within an attribute within json data?

Below I have posted an example snip of one business dataset from yelp which is imported into apache spark. I am aware as to how to take a slice of info based on an attribute so far. However how can i slice info of an attribute within an attribute. I have the following code below

rdd.filter(lambda x: 'dj' in x['Music']).take(5)

This code will return data that has the word 'dj' within 'Music'

However how can i take a slice of the data to show all attributes which contain 'dj' but also 'True' within that part?

I would expect the output to show all the businesses with 'music' in the attribute and within that to have a 'dj' attribute which is set to true

Hope this makes sense. Thanks

[{'business_id': 'vyutuvybuyb',

'attributes': {'Alcohol': 'full_bar',

'Music': {'dj': False,

'background_music': True,

'no_music': False,

'karaoke': False,

'live': False,

'video': False,

'jukebox': False},

'RestaurantsGoodForGroups': True,

'Caters': False,

'hours': {'Monday': '11:00-1:00',

'Tuesday': '11:00-1:00',

'Friday': '11:00-1:00',

'Wednesday': '11:00-1:00',

'Thursday': '11:00-1:00',

'Sunday': '11:00-0:00',

'Saturday': '11:00-2:00'}}]

i apologize if this question has already been asked. i have tried searching upon a solution but i dont know if i am using the right terminology to find the correct thing im looking for

Comment: Please add what would be the expected output?

Comment: sorry. i have edited the question